# Is it possible to make positional argument optional in URL in Django

Tags: django, url-rewriting, django-views

I have this in URL file

`(r'^new/(?P<object_class>\w+)/(?P<action>\w+)/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', create_object)`

NOw for URL like   `/new/book/edit/5` it is working fine

But if i do `/new/book/create` then it says nor URL matched.

Is it possible that third argumrent is optional so that i can use one URL rule for above cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(r'^new/(?P<object_class>\w+)/(?P<action>\w+)/((?P<object_id>\d+)/)?$', create_object)
```

This should do it. (Notice I wrapped `object_id` and the `/` in a `(..)?` to make it optional)

Now `object_id` *should* be none in the view.

Comment: Thanks buddy , your both answers were very confusing  but it worked.I just got confused which one worked before

Answer (score 0):

You can mark one of the arguments as optional with the regex char for 0 or 1 a question mark)  Using your example I used:

```
(r'^new/(?P<object_class>\w+)/(?P<action>\w+)(/(?P<object_id>\d+))?/$', create_object)
```

The important thing to note is that a trailing / should still be present.